# Entity Framework 6 - Retrieve Model Namespace

Tags: c#, model, entity-framework-6

In my Database first scenario I need to receive the namespace of mthe SSDL content. 
When looking at the edmx xml it was located under edmx:Edmx > edmx:Runtime > edmx:StorageModels > Schema as a tag

But I couldn't figure out or find any solution on how to receive this namespace.

Comment: Just curious: why? And can't you just get the namespace of an entity type?

Comment: When calling database functions I need to specify this namespace.... Just seeing, I'm talking in my question about the wrong namespace